# Windows Explorer does not provide options to burn to cd-rw

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, burning

Opening the CD Drive in Computer does not have a Burn to Disk drop area.

The disk is already formatted for CD/DVD Player use.

Other sites suggested:

1. [Check driver in Device Manager](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/99565-cd-dvd-burner-will-no-longer-burn.html). [Admin only. I'm boxed out.]
2. [Attempt to burn in safe mode, then attempt again in normal mode](http://www.sevenforums.com/music-pictures-video/298653-cant-burn-cd.html).
3. [Properly eject a flash drive](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/291564-32-windows-burn-dvds-more). [Didn't work.]

Comment: The default disk burning capabilities of Windows does not do well on CD-RW disks, at least, if you want those disks to work on anything besides Windows.  Just use third-party software.  Windows can record CD-RW disks it just means, you have to format the disk, then record the data again or use the multi-session option limiting the use to Windows 7 and above.

Comment: You sure the drive is actually a CD/DVD writer and not just a ROM?  You say the disk is "already formatted", what did you do to format it? Since you don't have Admin privileges on that computer, have you consulted with the admin of the system? Perhaps they've purposfully disallowed burning?

Comment: Company PCs.  Our new assets aren't displaying burn capabilities in Windows Explorer, even though the drives are clearly marked as DVD-RW.  Something is amiss. (We cannot install 3rd party software ourselves). Usually the most efficient use of time is to find a lead such that IT is put on the correct path when we ask for a fix.

Comment: Troubleshooting and supporting problems in corporate environment is off topic... If you are not a local administrator this right or privilege could be locked down to corporate policy. Contact your internal IT support

Comment: See this link.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314060